# Can't get opendir() to work to save my life

Tags: php, macos

I am a longtime developer (C/C++/Objective-C/Pascal/assembler) who's finally decided it's time to learn PHP.

I am writing some VERY simple scripts to try to feed data to an app I am developing in Objective C for iOS.

For now I am entering a URL to invoke my script in my browser and then looking at the output.

I have code that gets the directory name from the running script. I can append a subdirectory ("/files") to that directory, and then append a filename from the invoking URL, to build a full path to my file (e.g. "/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default/files/image.png")

If I set the header type and use `readfile($filePath)`, I can display the image to my browser window, so I know the path is well-formed.

My next step is to iterate through all the files in the directory "/files". I want to build a JSON message that tells my app about the contents of the file.

However, I can't get the @#$@#$ `opendir` command to work to save my life.

If I execute this line:

```
$handle = opendir($files_dir)
```

My script fails to run. I know the value in `$files_dir` is well formed because like I said I can use it to build a path to a file and display that file without a problem.

I've tried adding a balancing call to `closedir($handle)`, but it doesn't seem to matter.

I am running my script in Apple's OSX server. I am able to get it to run by invoking it from a browser, or by issuing a GET command from my test app in iOS... unless I try to use opendir().

What could be going wrong here?!? I'm getting very frustrated.

Comment: fails HOW? we can't help you with just one single line of code.

Comment: You may want to consider a better title.

Comment: Are there any error messages from this? Add `ini_set('display_errors',1);` to the top of your script and they should show up if they're not already.

Comment: Do you want to save a file? `opendir` is not required for that

Comment: @MarcB, fails as in I get no output in my browser window. Part of the problem is that I am used to working with an IDE and a source-level debugger. I don't know how to tell how it fails. I just get no output.

Comment: @Onimusha, I want my script to iterate through a list of the files in the directory, and generate JSON that it sends to my mobile device about those files. (This is a learning project, mostly on consuming JSON web services on the client side, but I need to be able to generate that info on the server-side, and I dead from the start)

Comment: @DuncanC Do `var_dump($handle)` if it succeeds you will get [resource handler](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.types.resource.php) otherwise false

Comment: @RahilWazir, when I have the opendir() command in my script, NONE of my output appears. The script silently fails. I added the `ini_set('display_errors',1);' command suggested by Machavity, and saw some missing quotes in another line of my code, but no other errors. I tried adding var_dump($handle), and don't see any output from that, either.

Comment: Stab in the dark: File/folder permissions? Maybe even a path issue.

Comment: Are you checking the output on the browser first? Or trying directly through application? Also how are you iterating through the dir? I think posting the code you have will really help instead of the one liner there

Comment: @Fred, I tried that. I have the permissions on the entire folder hierarchy and all the files set to 777.

Comment: Also, @ the negative voters, this guy has 17.9k rep - show some respect :)

Comment: @Onimusha, I have the code to iterate through the directory commented out. If I use the opendir() one-liner, then none of my printf() commands before or after do anything. Literally I add opendir(), and the entire script does nothing. Comment it and the closedir() command out, and the other code operates as expected.

Comment: @Onimusha What do you mean by **17.9K rep user**. It doesn't matter. If this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful should need to be downvoted.

Comment: Another stab in the dark: Since you're a C/C++/Objective-C/Pascal/assembler programmer, I can't help but notice the word "append" in your question. You wouldn't happen to be using the `+` sign by any chance to "append to"? As in `string::operator+=(Append to string)` If that's the case, PHP uses dots to append to; *just a wild guess.*

Comment: Nope. I already made and corrected that mistake.

Comment: @RahilWazir Ok I agree with you. His question doesn't merit an answer since he hasn't provided any additional code even after being asked plenty of times.

Comment: Gents, I was off composing a minimal fail-case for paste bin, which forced me to find my stupid mistake. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I feel really stupid. I was missing a semicolon. It was a syntax error, plain and simple. Sigh...